# locating eclipse view's parent

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Consider an rcp plugin, using eclipse IDE with different number of views, Each view can be moved to the left/right or bottom ctabs. I can get the list of views references with following:

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();

but I like to realize if the view is dragged and dropped to the left or to the right ctab. Or basically i'd like to get the parent of a view.

so for example in the picture, Tasklist view could be added to the left ctab or to the right ctab. I'm interested in finding which one includes my view

[image]

Comment: You can use `IWorkbenchPage.getViewStack` to get the views in the stack containing the view. Other than that I don't think there is an easy way to get this information.

Comment: unfortunately the coloumns on left and right are not views so getviewstack wont help. they are part of the perspective layout. so when I create the perspective I use the following : layout.addView(MyView.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.69f, editorArea);   and this adds it to the right pagelayout but as I tried I couldnt get pagelayout at runtime.